# How to create feature vector in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am reading a csv as a data frame in scala as below:

```
+-----------+------------+
|x          |y           |
+-----------+------------+
|          0|           0|
|          0|          33|
|          0|          58|
|          0|          96|
|          0|           1|
|          1|          21|
|          0|          10|
|          0|          65|
|          1|           7|
|          1|          28|
+-----------+------------+
```

Then I create the label and feature vector as below:

```
val assembler =  new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("y"))
  .setOutputCol("features")


    val output = assembler.transform(daf).select($"x".as("label"), $"features")

  println(output.show)
```

The output is as:

```
+-----------+------------+ 
|label | features | 
+-----------+------------+ 
| 0.0| 0.0| 
| 0.0| 33.0| 
| 0.0| 58.0| 
| 0.0| 96.0| 
| 0.0| 1.0| 
| 0.0| 21.0| 
| 0.0| 10.0| 
| 1.0| 65.0| 
| 1.0| 7.0| 
| 1.0| 28.0| 
+-----------+------------+
```

But instead of this I  want the output to be like in the below format

```
+-----+------------------+ 
|label| features | 
+-----+------------------+ 
| 0.0|(1,[1],[0]) | 
| 0.0|(1,[1],[33]) | 
| 0.0|(1,[1],[58]) | 
| 0.0|(1,[1],[96]) | 
| 0.0|(1,[1],[1]) | 
| 1.0|(1,[1],[21]) | 
| 0.0|(1,[1],[10]) | 
| 0.0|(1,[1],[65]) | 
| 1.0|(1,[1],[7]) | 
| 1.0|(1,[1],[28]) | 
+-----------+------------+
```

I tried

```
 val assembler =  new VectorAssembler()
      .setInputCols(Array("y").map{x => "(1,[1],"+x+")"})
      .setOutputCol("features")
```

But did not work.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you use VectorAssembler.

You need to give the names of your input columns. i.e

```
new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("features"))
```

You'll face eventually another issue considering the data that you have shared. It's not much a vector if it's one point. (your `features` columns)

It should be used with 2 or more columns. i.e :

```
new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("f1","f2","f3"))
```